# Altium Designer: Not assigning all the sub-parts of a device

Tags: altium, optimization

I've been banging my head against this one for a while now and can't seem to find and answer anywhere.
I have a multi-channel design that uses a a quad comparator as the base part. However in the repeated sub-sheet I only make use of 2 of the 4 comparators.
When I compile the design and check the BOM I get 16 devices where I'm expecting 12. The 16 devices are all only partially used.
How can I get Altium to optimise the subpart usage?

Comment: Then answer is probably to take it out of the repeated portion, which is not the answer you'd like, but..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't. If you want to optimize part usage, then introduce multiple levels of hierarchy where you bring the partly used comparator out of the repeated subsheet up one level higher.
This will limit your ability to use the REPEAT statement, just create N instances of your design - in my opinion it's much more intuitive than using the REPEAT statement.

Comment: Well that's not very efficient. In my case I have 4 copies of the same subsheet which sits ina repeated sheet. The hierarchy is top sheet->repeted subsheet->copied sub-subsheet. The comparators are used in buth sub-sheet and sub-sub sheet level. I remember using this kind of design over 20years ago in another tool and it optimised the component use for me, even highlighting un-used sub-parts... I guess I'll have to figure out a different way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

In Altium a part cannot span over multiple channels; if it did, things would get complicated quite quickly.

The best solution is to split it by comparator, at least that is what I have done in the past to get around this issue.